# SLR - simple linear regression (in R, but about the math behind, not the programming)

Tags: math, linear-regression

So I have some problems understanding simple linear regression. I did read a lot, so  I have the basic ideas in mind, but I cannot quite follow when we do one. So I have this equation:

```
yi = a + bxi + ei
```

Okay so I do realize this is the equation for a straight line, even though I do wonder about the "ei" as I cannot find it on the internet, but my professor keeps using it.

So I want to find a and b, so I can find a straight line which I hope isn't to far away from my data (is that right?). I know I can calculate that, but this is not my question.

I hope it is alright if I add my example here, so I can explain what I'm doing:
data set

```
x        y
8        6.4
8        6.8
3        1.7
2        2.3
2        3.8
1        2.3
1        5.0
1        4.0
1        3.4
0        2.3
```

calculation everything that's needed, I get:
b = 0.4599
a = 2.55827

(and doing the `lm` with R shows me it is right).
Now if I draw this straight line `abline(2.55827,0.4599)` (entering the intercept first??),
it shows me that this is just not a good line and looking at the table I would totally agree.
But do I understand right? If the x|y points arrange like they do through the given values (meaning without a specific pattern), there's just no good line to find, so I can only find a rather good one.

Can someone maybe help me out here?

Comment: This may be a better fit for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Okay so I do realize this is the equation for a straight line, even though I do wonder about the "ei" as I cannot find it on the internet, but my professor keeps using it.

It's not the equation for a line. *y<sub>i</sub> = a + bx<sub>i</sub>* is the equation for a line. That e<sub>i</sub> is the error between this straight line given by a and b and your measurements. In other words, *e<sub>i</sub> = y<sub>i</sub> - (a + bx<sub>i</sub>)*.

What linear regression does is to find the values for *a* and *b* that minimizes the sum of the squares of those error terms. This fit is not necessarily a good one; it's just the best possible (in a least squares sense). The size of the residual gives you an idea of how good the fit was.

To be able to make sense of whether the fit is good or bad, you need to know not just the residuals but also the errors in the individual measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Gil Strang is one of the great applied mathematicians.  He can explain linear algebra and least squares like no one else:

http://videolectures.net/mit18085f07_strang_lec04/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old question, however there is a nice article that explains the mathematics behind linear regression as well as step wise coding of the mathematics in R language:
http://www.codophile.com/programming-linear-regression-in-r/

I hope this will help.